# Can't get data with dbplyr from shiny-server

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny-server, r-dbi, dbplyr

I'm trying to get data from AWS SQL Server.
This code works fine from local PC, but it didn't work from shiny-server (ubuntu).

```
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)    

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver = "FreeTDS",
                 server = "aws server",
                 database = "",
                 uid = "",
                 pwd = "")
tbl(con, "shops")
dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT *
                  FROM shops")

"R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)"

packageVersion("dbplyr")
[1] ‘1.2.1.9000’

packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘0.7.4’
packageVersion("DBI")
[1] ‘0.7.15’
```

I have next error:

```
tbl(con, "shops")
Error: <SQL> 'SELECT *
FROM "shops" AS "zzz2"
WHERE (0 = 1)'
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42000: [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'shops'.
```

But  `dbGetQuery(con,"SELECT * FROM shops")` works fine.
Can you explain what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is more likely because the FreeTDS driver does not return the `class` that `dbplyr` expects to see in order to use the MS SQL translation.  The workaround is to take the result of `class(con)` and then  add the following lines right after you connect, but before calling `tbl()`.  Replace the `[you class name]` with the results of the `class(con)` call:

```
sql_translate_env.[your class name] <- dbplyr:::`sql_translate_env.Microsoft SQL Server`
sql_select.[your class name]<- dbplyr:::`sql_select.Microsoft SQL Server`
```